# Cost distance of one raster using routes of separate cost distance in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cost-path, least-cost, cost-surface

Is there a way, using ArcGIS Desktop, I can calculate the cost distance for one raster of cost values but instead of using the least cost distances from that raster, using the routes/paths determined from a separate cost raster?

For instance, say I have a cost raster for energy expenditure based on slope but I want energy costs taking the least cost distances for another raster such the vegetation density. The product would essentially be the total sum of said energy values but while walking through the thinner vegetation if possible.

I need this for an entire surface rather than a path.

Comment: Convert backlinks from vegetation analysis to flow direction raster using Int(pow(2, blink-1)) or reclassification by table. Compute flow accumulation  using energy surface as weight.

Comment: @FelixIP This returns a typical flow accumulation raster of stream lines. Is there a method which will return something more similar to cost distance—with only the minimum cost to each cell?

Comment: Use flow length instead with weight raster.